# "onClick" not working after building the project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a `GatsbyImage` component which is styled using styled components. It has an `onClick` event listener which is used to trigger a popup with the image.

So while I'm running the project on my PC using `npm run develop` everything is working as it should. I can click on an image and the `openImageModalHandler` function runs.

The issue only appears after I deploy the website to a service like Netlify or Gatsby Cloud.

So if I access the home page of the website first and then go to a page that contains an image (generated from a template) everything works as it should.

But if I go directrly to a page that is generated from a template and contains an image the `onClick` event listener doesn't appear on the images. I even added a `console.log` confirms that the event listener is not added to the images.

Here is a link to the home page: https://goofy-beaver-7fc18b.netlify.app/

Here is a link to a page with images: [https://goofy-beaver-7fc18b.netlify.app/Assassin's%20Creed%20III/](https://goofy-beaver-7fc18b.netlify.app/Assassin%27s%20Creed%20III/)

GitHub: https://github.com/DantchoLV9/gamer8

The image component:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image";
import useKeypress from "../../hooks/useKeypress";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Image = ({ image, alt }) => {
    const [imageModalState, setImageModelState] = useState(false);

    const openImageModalHandler = () => {
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        console.log("test");
        setImageModelState(true);
    };

    const closeImageModalHandler = (e) => {
        if (e !== undefined) {
            if (e.target.classList.contains("background")) {
                document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
                setImageModelState(false);
            }
        } else {
            document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
            setImageModelState(false);
        }
    };

    useKeypress("Escape", closeImageModalHandler);

    return (
        <>
            <StyledImage
                onClick={openImageModalHandler}
                image={getImage(image)}
                alt={alt}
            />
            {imageModalState && (
                <ImageModalBackground
                    className="background"
                    onClick={closeImageModalHandler}
                >
                    <ModalImage image={getImage(image)} alt={alt} />
                </ImageModalBackground>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

const StyledImage = styled((props) => <GatsbyImage {...props} />)`
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
`;

const ImageModalBackground = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0rem 5rem;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    @media (max-width: 780px) {
        padding: 0rem 2rem;
    }
`;

const ModalImage = styled((props) => <GatsbyImage {...props} />)`
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    cursor: default;
`;

export default Image;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting OnClick on styled component is cuasing this.
i just downloaded and build your repo and changed this to work:

```
         <span
        tabIndex={-1}
        role="button"
        onClick={openImageModalHandler}
        onKeyPress={(event) => event.key === "Enter" && openImageModalHandler}
        />
          <StyledImage
            image={getImage(image)}
            alt={alt}
          />
        </span>
```

Comment: That seems to have worked, but now I get `Visible, non-interactive elements with click handlers must have at least one keyboard listener` and `Static HTML elements with event handlers require a role`.

Comment: I updated the answer to cover that part.  I usually use span with role="button" and a onKeyPress function.

Comment: That's great mate. Works perfectly. Could you also explain what `onKeyPress` does since I don't really get it?

Comment: its a part of accessibility for the web, It's for the people that use the Keyboard to navigate your site.  https://www.a11yproject.com/checklist/#keyboard